# PHP preg_match dont give the right answer

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have a regex. I checked it in a lot of online regex tester and it's work in there. But when i want to use it in my code, it's doesn't return the right data.

The imput string is:

> Some Name (year) (url)    OR    Some name (url)

The year section is not allways displayed

Here is my code:

```
$regex = '/(.*?(?:[ ]?\(\d{4}\))?)[ ]?\((.*?)\)$/';
preg_match($regex, $highlight[$row['id']]['person_image'][0], $person_image);
```

What i want is the name with the year (if exits), end the url without bracket, but after that the $person_image is contain that:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(105) "Zorán (1998) (gallery/keyframe/2010/07/21/m2-30414/m2-30414-11333200.jpg)" [1]=> string(6) "Zorán" [2]=> string(96) "1998) (gallery/keyframe/2010/07/21/m2-30414/m2-30414-11333200.jpg" }
```

Is there any problem with my regex?

Comment: Can you setup a PHP fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: please put a demonstration.your question is bit unclear to us.